# Access a saved ipython notebook on an external drive (mac)

Tags: macos, ipython, anaconda

I'm trying to access an ipython notebook that was saved to an external HD.  Is this possible?

Specifically, I saved an ipython notebook to a dropbox folder (locally synced) on one computer.  I am now trying to open that ipython notebook on another computer that syncs to the same dropbox account -- only computer b's dropbox folder is on an external HD.

This seems so basic, but I've looked everywhere for an answer on this and am afraid I'm missing something more fundamental here.

Comment: How are you launching the notebook? If you start it in the directory where your notebooks are, it should be able to see them.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I'm launching the notebook from Anaconda's launcher.  It looks like it launches in my home folder (user root? I don't know if that's the right term). In any case, I can't see the external HD beneath my home folder, so I can't get to the local dropbox folder that's on the external HD.  So two questions: 1) do you know if you can change where Anaconda launches the notebook? 2) is there a way of navigating to an external HD from your home folder? Thanks for any help (I know this is basic).

Comment: The notebook can only see directories under where it is started. I don't know if Anaconda can launch elsewhere. If you go to a command line, you should be able to `cd` to the relevant directory, then run `/path/to/anaconda/bin/ipython notebook` to launch the notebook there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a symbolic link to your external drive; store this link somewhere on the main drive.

For example, my Dropbox folder is on an external flash card, so I used a **terminal session** to do the following:

> $ ln -s /Volumes/SDCARD/Dropbox ~/Documents/DB

(Screenshots [here](http://carpediemsystems.co.uk/2015/10/08/os-x-ipython-notebooks-on-an-an-external-drive-with-anaconda/))

Answer (score 0):

From terminal, if you have Anaconda installed, type:

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/Volumes/NameofExternalDrive
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).