# Opening jupyterlab in my external harddrive

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I am trying to access jupyter notebooks, through jupyter lab, that are on an external harddrive on my mac. Whenever I open jupyter lab though it only allows me to access files directly on my computer's drive. I cannot seem to find/open the anaconda prompt where I could use (if i am understanding other similar questions correctly):

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=Volume/name of disk/
```

I've also tried using this in the terminal however I get the error that there is no such notebook dir.

Comment: I think what you are inquiring about is already covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55369484/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33007653/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75645916/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46755604/8508004). In particular, if the first couple don't help you, see [this comment by 
r.burak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46755604/how-to-navigate-to-a-different-directory-in-jupyter-notebook#comment116179563_46755604): "create a symbolic link to all other drives at your root directory. It works lika a magic."

Comment: Also https://github.com/jpmorganchase/jupyter-fs